# Unable to click on an out of screen Button using Selenium(Java) and getting ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, exception, automation

I am not able to click on a submit button which is out of screen using Selenium(Java). If I decrease the browser text size, manually I am able to click. I tried below solution but it's not working.

N.B - It's not a scrollable screen.
**Option 1:**

```
WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.xpath(submitxpath));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", submit);
```

**Option 2:**

```
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", submit );
```

**Option 3:**

```
executor.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + submit.getLocation().getX() + "," + (submit.getLocation().getY()) + ");");
submit.click();
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried with `Explicit Wait`?

Comment: How would you click it in manual approach? If the button is out of screen and the view is not scrollable isn't it a defect of web application?

Comment: @KunduK - It's not the problem with element view. Webelement is present in the screen but not reachable at it's out of screen.

Comment: @AlexeyR.- Yes, you're correct, but the Dev team has developed for higher resolution screen and I'm accessing with my laptop that has smaller screen. So right now they don't want t fix this issue rather we need to bear it.

Comment: Does option 1 not work? I believe it should.

Comment: @amythious have you tried to set up bigger dimensions for your window? I am not sure it can be bigger than your screen, but in headless mode you can set whatever screen size you need.

Comment: .click() method will click on the button whether it is on or offscreen.  (it will scroll it into view) Include your exceptions so we can see what the issue is here.